# Windows 10: introduced router and can't see other computers in network

Tags: windows, router

When I'm connected via cable to the building's network socket I can see all other computers in the network.
Now I introduced a router and can only see computers in the router's sub-network. Is there something I can do to be able to see other computers in the network to which now router is directly connected?
I disabled firewall on the router.

Cheers

Comment: nothing to programming

Comment: Yeah, instead of creating yet another account on some Windows-dedicated-or-whatever forum I thought I would ask about that fellow programmers. Sue me

Comment: (Yes, there are several things you can do -- you could tell your router to proxy broadcast packets, you could set up a WINS server, you could configure Active Directory to be used for discovery... but none of those are on-topic here).

Answer (score -1):

Router is a Layer 3 device for routing network traffic between networks. But not broadcast by default. So you can see only PCs in your subnet. Because broadcast is allowed. So you have to find a solution how to allow the broadcast traffic in your router. If it not possible you can't get what you want by simple solution.